# C++ quicksort implementation crashes; also style advices

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort

I'm quite a newbie and implemented my first quicksort algorithm in C++ today :)
It works, but only for a few numbers, when I try to enter more than ~20 numbers (or big numbers) it crashes, and I don't know why. Is it so badly written?

Also feel free to critice my code! Are there better ways to do it? E.g how can I implement that the user can enter numbers until he types in a specific word?

Thanks!! :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//SORTING FUNCTION
void sort(double* numbers, int end, int start = 0)
{
    //END THE RECURSION
    if ((end-start) <= 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    //SORTING PART
    else
    {
        int pivot = (start + end) / 2;
        int left = pivot - 1;
        int right = pivot + 1;

        //SORT ALL THE NUMBERS RIGHT OF THE PIVOT
        do
        {
            if (numbers[left] >= numbers[pivot])
            {
                double temp;
                temp = numbers[left];
                for (int i = left; i < pivot; i++)
                {
                    numbers[i] = numbers[i + 1];
                }
                numbers[pivot] = temp;
                pivot--;
                left--;
            }
            else if (numbers[left] < numbers[pivot])
            {
                left--;
            }
        } while (left >= start);

        //SORT ALL THE NUMBERS RIGHT OF THE PIVOT
        do
        {
            if (numbers[right] <= numbers[pivot])
            {
                double temp;
                temp = numbers[right];
                for (int i = right; i > pivot; i--)
                {
                    numbers[i] = numbers[i - 1];
                }
                numbers[pivot] = temp;
                pivot++;
                right++;
            }
            else if (numbers[right] > numbers[pivot])
            {
                right++;
            }
        } while (right <= end);

        //SPLIT THE ARRAY INTO TO SUB ARRAYS AND CALL THE SORT FUNCTION
        sort(numbers, pivot - 1); //LEFT SIDE OF THE PIVOT
        sort(numbers, end, pivot + 1); //RIGHT SIDE OF THE PIVOT
}

int main()
{
    //IMPUT NUMBERS
    cout << "IMPUT NUMBERS. END WITH CHARACTER." << endl << endl;
    double numbersTemp[100];
    int counter = -1; //-1 SO IT POINTS TO THE RIGHT INDEX
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        double temp;
        cin >> temp;
        if (cin)
        {
            numbersTemp[i] = temp;
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            break; //BREAK WHEN SOMETHING ELSE THAN A DOUBLE IS ENTERED
        }
    }

    //INITIALISE ARRAY IN RIGHT SIZE
    double* numbers = new double[counter + 1];

    //PASS THE VALUES TO THE NEW ARRAY
    for (int i = 0; i < counter + 1; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = numbersTemp[i];
    }

    //SORT IT
    sort(numbers, counter);

    //GIVE OUT THE SORTET NUMBERS
    cout << endl << "SORTED NUMBERS: " << endl;
    for (int k = 0; k <= counter; k++)
    {
        cout << numbers[k] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    //CLEAR USED MEMORY SPACE
    delete[] numbers;

    //END PROGRAMM (DUH)
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: well, dunno, it works haha. I just decided to take the middle element as the pivot element..

Comment: It's not really quicksort. In your for loop when sorting left and right of the pivot you swap alla values between pivot and left and essentially doing an insertion sort.

Comment: The starting point of the "left sort" isn't necessarily zero — consider the recursive call on the upper half of the array.

Comment: aaaahh true! changed it to `sort(numbers, pivot - 1, left+1)`
and it works now, but still crashes at ~ 20 inputs..

@HenrikNilsson: how would it have to work differently for it to be a quicksort?

Answer (score 0):

I reworked your sorting code some to make it more efficient

```
//END THE RECURSION
if ((end - start) <= 0)
{
    return;
}

//SORTING PART
else
{
    int pivot = (start + end) / 2;
    int left = start;   // Set left to first element
    int right = end;    // Set right to last element

    while (left < right)
    {
        if (numbers[left] > numbers[pivot]) // If left is greater then pivot swap them
        {
            double temp = numbers[left];
            numbers[left] = numbers[pivot];
            numbers[pivot] = temp;

            pivot = left; // Pivot is now left
        }

        if (numbers[right] < numbers[pivot]) // If right is smaller then pivot
        {
            double temp = numbers[right];
            numbers[right] = numbers[pivot];
            numbers[pivot] = temp;

            pivot = right; // Pivot is now right
        }

        left++;
        right--;
    }

    //SPLIT THE ARRAY INTO TO SUB ARRAYS AND CALL THE SORT FUNCTION
    sort(numbers, pivot - 1); //LEFT SIDE OF THE PIVOT
    sort(numbers, end, pivot + 1); //RIGHT SIDE OF THE PIVOT
}
```

Left and right move from the end of the array instead of from the middle. This way the left and right part of the array will be sorted and only pivot need to move around. It is based on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3OLTJlwyIqQ) if you want to see how it works.